# How to programmatically choose a context menu item in another app?

Tags: delphi, winapi, contextmenu, message, sendmessage

The target app is written in Delphi (win32 not .NET) and is closed-source.

The action I want to invoke is called Copy, but there is no obvious keyboard shortcut. (Ctrl+Insert does the wrong thing and Ctrl+C does nothing)

I can find my target `HWND` and persuade it to open the context menu (it responds to `WM_RBUTTONDOWN/UP` not `WM_CONTEXTMENU`). From the menu `HWND` I can even obtain the menu handle via `MN_GETHMENU` and find the menu item I want. I just don't know the details of how to "choose" the item. It doesn't help that the menu is "modeless", ie. its `HWND` is not owned, so I don't know which of many hidden `TPUtilWindow` windows is the real owner - otherwise I could probably just send it a `WM_COMMAND` and not even pop up the menu, which would be preferable.

Although I am sure it facilitates all sorts of hacks, I would prefer not to inject code into the target process.

Answers accepted in any language.

Comment: I feel there would be some security implications if something like that were possible, since that would mean one can fool apps into thinking they are getting input from the keyboard/mouse when in fact it's coming from another app! Cannot think of any concrete example right now though...

Comment: If you're running untrusted apps you've already lost anyway. But that raises a point - this works on XP... I wonder if it'd work on Vista / 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you're able to send it `WM_RBUTTONDOWN/UP` messages and it responds.  If so, can you also send `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` messages?  As long as you know the structure of the menu and it doesn't change, try telling the app that someone's pressing the Down arrow X number of times and then hitting ENTER.  That seems like the simplest solution to me...

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although for brevity I sent WM_CHAR not WM_KEYDOWN/UP.

Comment: Also, I just sent the accelerator key, not cursor down / enter.